# Minecraft Super Secret Settings

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I've tried everything and nothing will work.
[image]

It's stuck at "normal/regular" settings.
Anyone help me turn it back to normal?

Comment: That looks like the 3d setting, the really old kind which uses red and blue lens glasses. i remember Minecraft having an option in the graphics settings for turning that off

Comment: Any way to fix it?

Comment: omfg nvm fixed it ... its in Video Settings: Other: 3D Anaglyph

Answer (score 4):

Pressing <kbd>F4</kbd> will disable the shaders caused by super secret settings, but this looks more like `3D Anaglyph`, which can be turned off in `Video Settings`:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/m3qVD2F.png]

Answer (score 2):

It seems as if you are using the real old [Anaglyph 3D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaglyph_3D)

> Anaglyph 3D is the name given to the stereoscopic 3D effect achieved by means of encoding each eye's image using filters of different (usually chromatically opposite) colors, typically red and cyan. Anaglyph 3D images contain two differently filtered colored images, one for each eye. When viewed through the "color-coded" "anaglyph glasses", each of the two images reaches the eye it's intended for, revealing an integrated stereoscopic image. The visual cortex of the brain fuses this into perception of a three-dimensional scene or composition.

Minecraft however has a setting for this located in the [Video Settings](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Settings#Video_Settings)

[image: Video Settings]

however it does have some problems

> ### Q: How does "Anaglyph 3D" work?
>
> **A:** You can play Minecraft in astounding 3D-o-scope by turning this option on and wearing red-cyan 3D glasses. However, you can't use cinema 3D glasses.
>
> - The clouds will be glitched and appear to be in the foreground with Fancy graphics.
> - The first person view of the item currently held will appear to be doubled, overlapping each other.
> - Minecraft does not support any other kind of 3D display yet. Old nVidia 3D drivers which support OpenGL may work.

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Q:_How_does_.22Anaglyph_3D.22_work.3F)